# Loading <li> from jsonp looses JQM formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm loading data in through jsonp for a jquery mobile app. When I do it statically it works nicely and has all the JQM formatting.

However, when I pass the data in through .append the li items don't have the formatting

```
<div data-role="content" class="listview-pets">
     <ul data-role="listview" id="listpetsList" data-inset="true"></ul>
</div>
```

That's the UL that encompasses it.

The code is:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
     $("#listpetsList").append("<li><a href=\"#select-pet-dialog\" data-rel=\"dialog\" data-selected=\"1\" data-transition=\"flip\"><img src='" + data[index].Picture + "'><h2>" + data[index].Name + "</h2><p>Type</p></li>");
});
```

I assume it's something to do with JQM pre styling the elements but i'm injecting afterwards. How can i force it to update?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing function used for listview content enhancement:

Change this:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    $("#listpetsList").append("<li><a href=\"#select-pet-dialog\" data-rel=\"dialog\" data-selected=\"1\" data-transition=\"flip\"><img src='" + data[index].Picture + "'><h2>" + data[index].Name + "</h2><p>Type</p></li>");
});
```

To this:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    $("#listpetsList").append("<li><a href=\"#select-pet-dialog\" data-rel=\"dialog\" data-selected=\"1\" data-transition=\"flip\"><img src='" + data[index].Picture + "'><h2>" + data[index].Name + "</h2><p>Type</p></li>");
});
$("#listpetsList").listview('refresh');
```

This one will also work:

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
    $("#listpetsList").append("<li><a href=\"#select-pet-dialog\" data-rel=\"dialog\" data-selected=\"1\" data-transition=\"flip\"><img src='" + data[index].Picture + "'><h2>" + data[index].Name + "</h2><p>Type</p></li>");
});
$("#listpetsList").enhanceWithin();
```

Read more about this topic **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**.